# monstrous multiple join that needs limiting the results to 144

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

the story is a freelancer programmer has disappeared leaving an unfinished work to a front-ender - including some MySQL queries. 
I can manage simple stuff, but this thing is beyond my skills.
The query returns all the products from the shop sorted by

```
products_date_added
```

while it's supposed to pull only 144 newest results.
I tried adding limit 144 in the end of it, but apparently it doesn't work that way.

The query is as follows:

```
select  p.products_id,   
        p.products_status,
        p.products_quantity,
        if(length(pd1.products_name),pd1.products_name, pd.products_name) as products_name,
        if(p.products_image_lrg is null, p.products_image, p.products_image_lrg) as products_image,
        p.products_model,
        p.products_price,
        pd.products_description_short,
        p.products_tax_class_id,
        p.products_date_added,
        p.products_master,
        p.products_master_status,
        p.products_listing_status,
        m.manufacturers_name 
from products_description pd,
     products p
left join products_description pd1 on pd1.products_id = p.products_id
    and pd1.language_id='1'
    and pd1.affiliate_id = '0'
left join products_prices pp on p.products_id = pp.products_id
    and pp.groups_id = '0'
    and pp.currencies_id = '0'
left join manufacturers m on (p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id)
where p.products_status > 0
    and (p.products_master='0' or p.products_master is null or p.products_master='')
    and p.products_master_status!='1'
    and pd.affiliate_id = 0
    and p.products_id = pd.products_id
    and if(pp.products_group_price is null,
    pp.products_group_price != -1 )
    and pd.affiliate_id = 0
    and pd.language_id = '1'
order by p.products_date_added DESC, products_name
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean by *I tried adding limit 144 in the end of it, but apparently it doesn't work that way.*? There's a LIMIT in MySQL and when the result set is ordered the right way it should return the correct data.

Comment: Do not mix implicit (comma-) join syntax with explicit JOIN syntax. In fact, don't use comma-joins at all. They're harder to read, and evaluate in a different order from what you might expect. When combined with an OUTER JOIN, this can prove fatal. That said, I appreciate that this isn't your code!!

Comment: LIMIT 144 should work.  You say it doesn't work?  What does it do?

Comment: LIMIT in the end of the query does nothing in this case. Query lists all the products in the shop sorted by products_date_added pulling additional data from joined tables, which is utilized by filters module. Maybe a sub-query on "products" table limiting them to the newest 144 records would do the trick? Please, help! It's totally not my field :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment this might be what you want. I simply moved the join between `products` and `products_description` into a Derived Table (subquery) adding the `LIMIT`:

```
select  p.products_id,   
        p.products_status,
        p.products_quantity,
        if(length(pd1.products_name),pd1.products_name, p.products_name) as products_name,
        if(p.products_image_lrg is null, p.products_image, p.products_image_lrg) as products_image,
        p.products_model,
        p.products_price,
        p.products_description_short,
        p.products_tax_class_id,
        p.products_date_added,
        p.products_master,
        p.products_master_status,
        p.products_listing_status,
        m.manufacturers_name 
from 
    (
      select * -- you might have to list the actual columns to avoid a "duplicate name" error
      from products_description pd
      join products p on p.products_id = pd.products_id
      where p.products_status > 0
        and (p.products_master='0' or p.products_master is null
              or p.products_master='')
        and p.products_master_status!='1'
        and pd.affiliate_id = 0     
        and if(pp.products_group_price is null,
                pp.products_group_price != -1 )
        and pd.affiliate_id = 0
        and pd.language_id = '1'
      order by p.products_date_added DESC, products_name
      LIMIT 144
    ) p
left join products_description pd1 on pd1.products_id = p.products_id
    and pd1.language_id='1'
    and pd1.affiliate_id = '0'
left join products_prices pp on p.products_id = pp.products_id
    and pp.groups_id = '0'
    and pp.currencies_id = '0'
left join manufacturers m on (p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id)
order by p.products_date_added DESC, products_name
```